# CSS hover effect on certain condition (ie contains text)

Tags: html, css, hover, ag-grid

I want my css hover style to only happen when the inner span(with class "ag-header-group-text") is not empty (ie showing text). Is this possible through the css only?

https://jsfiddle.net/N8qah/13/

```
<div class="ag-header-group-cell ag-header-group-cell-with-group" style="width: 80px;">
    <div class="ag-header-cell-resize"></div>
    <div class="ag-header-group-cell-label"><span class="ag-header-group-text">TEST</span><span class="ag-header-expand-icon"><svg width="10" height="10"><polygon points="0,0 10,5 0,10"></polygon></svg></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed my css to this which works in that it does't active unless the inner span is not empty - the only issue is the span is highlighted instead of the most outerdiv that the hover happens on

```
.ag-header-group-cell:hover  span.ag-header-group-text:not(:empty) {
    background-color: #00008A;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes It's possible:

```
a:hover div.toshow:not(:empty) { display:block; }
```

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/N8qah/222/

See more details about `:empty` and compatibility:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aempty

Comment: Thanks - this is closer but not exactly what I need. I've updated the question with your suggestion though.

Comment: If I understand you fine, you can't make it, because with CSS you can select the parent element. However, `:empty` only works when is totally empty the element. An space, a line break, etc, works as non empty. You need javascript to find the element, see if it's empty an access to the parent. With css it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

you could target any child selectors , try this:

```
.ag-header-group-cell >*:hover {
     background-color: #00008A;
}
```

Comment: nope - seems like that killed all hovering effect :)